# Camera plugin in flutter making callback after taking picture

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

I am trying to capture image using camera in flutter. Image should be captured, for that using takePicture method. I am understanding whether the image is capturing or not, in debug, I got cameracallback exception, this code when I click on button screen blinks. Its not navigating.

````
        final path = picture.path;
        final bytes = await File(path).readAsBytes();
        final img.Image? image = img.decodeImage(bytes);
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomePage(image: image),
          ),
        );```
````